# Explode my Array, remove dash from key, then Implode it back together

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

What I want to do is remove the `-` dash from the key in my array and then rebuild it back together with a space in place of the `-`.

Sample array

```
$pages = array(

    'Administrator' => array(
        'network-administrator' => array('title' => 'Network '.$li_1, 'description' => 'Network '.$li_1.' '.$temp_content, 'post' => '<p>Network '.$li_1.' '.$temp_content.'.</p>'),
        'database administrator' => array('title' => 'Database '.$li_1, 'description' => 'Database '.$li_1.' '.$temp_content, 'post' => '<p>Database '.$li_1.' '.$temp_content.'.</p>'),
    ),

    'Analyst' => array(
        'business systems analyst' => array('title' => 'Business Systems '.$li_2, 'description' => 'Business Systems '.$li_2.' '.$temp_content, 'post' => '<p>Business Systems '.$li_2.' '.$temp_content.'.</p>'),
        'data-analyst' => array('title' => 'Data '.$li_2, 'description' => 'Data '.$li_2.' '.$temp_content, 'post' => '<p>Data '.$li_2.' '.$temp_content.'.</p>'),
    ),

);
```

As you can see there is a dash `-` in some of the keys. Some already have spaces. The ones that have dashes need to be replaced with spaces.

I know this sounds weird, "why not just hard code them all with spaces" right? Well I need both arrays to check for conditions within my php scripts.

I'm not sure how to go about exploding the array, removing the dashes and then imploding it back together.

I think it would be something like this.

```
explode('-', $pages[ucfirst($occupation)];
```

then implode

```
implode(' ', $pages[ucfirst($occupation)]);
```

But I know that won't get all of the children arrays within the top level array.

Not sure how to go about this.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you can't reference keys, you could just transfer them into a new one, then just a simple replace on those keys (provided the structure is fixed):

```
$new_pages = array();
foreach($pages as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $k => $v) {
        $k = str_replace('-', ' ', $k);
        $new_pages[$key][$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean if the structure is fixed?

Comment: @Mike what i mean that if its going to be more dimensions, if the dimensions (like this structure) is going to be fixed, its another scenario, but anyways, im glad this helped

Comment: yes the dimensions will not change. I don't foresee going another dimension deep in the array.

Comment: @Mike oh okay thats good to know, this simple loop will do just fine, glad this helped

Comment: yes thank you. And if you don't mind, can you explain what this part of in the loop does exactly? `$new_pages[$key][$k] = $v;`

Comment: @Mike that part right there is just a simple transfer, see the `$key` will be the `Administrator, analyst, etc..`, now `$k` which is the the subkeys: `network-administrator, data-analyst, etc..`, so the replacement must took place on those `$k`, like the shown answer, now right now we'll need to replace those `-` with `<spaces>`, just a simple str_replace will do, and then reassign them to another container since you cannot make changes on the original

Comment: ok I am starting to get hang of it. Basically `$new_pages[$key][$k] = $v;` is the same as saying `$pages as $key => $values` in the foreach?

Comment: @Mike `$key => $values` is the parent array, so if you're going to interpret that line it will be like: `$new_pages['Administrator']['network administrator'] = array('title' => Network..) ... ` and so on, its just a simple transfer

Comment: Got it. Would you mind checking out my other question I have. I just posted an edit to be more specific as to what I need. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072265/get-parameter-value-from-form-select-instead-of-querystring/26072302?noredirect=1#comment40850535_26072302

Comment: @Mike okay i'l examine the question, if i can understand it more, i'll try to answer

Comment: @Mike i've seen your question, i think the first answer should suffice, that would basically still my answer if i would too. just access the get variables thru `$_GET`, the answer also has a whitelist setup checking which is also good

Comment: I have a new question I think you would be able to help me. It requires making an adjustment to the code you already gave me. Hope you can help. I'm learning PHP and getting better. Here's the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077917/compare-string-to-sub-key-value-in-php-array-partial-match?noredirect=1#comment40860418_26077917