# get parameter value from form select instead of querystring

Tags: php, forms, query-string, url-parameters, selectedindex

I have a URL structure with query string and parameter called `position`.

example:

```
http://computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?occupation=administrator&position=network+administrator
```

I also have a form select option drop down list with the form select name of `position`.

example:

```
<form action="/jobs/" method="GET" id="menuform">

<select name="occupation" onChange="populate(this.id,\'position\')">
<option selected="" disabled="">Select Occupation</option>
<option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
</select>

<select name="position" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<option selected="" disabled="">Select Position</option>
<option value="network administrator">Network Administrator</option>
</select>

</form>
```

When the user makes a selection, it sends the option values to the action attribute with the select name="position" as the parameter to use in the query string.

My question is, how do I access the form select values separately from the query string values?

I use the _GET method to call the value from the query string parameter.

example:

```
$position = isset($_GET['position']) ? ($_GET['position']) : '';
```

Apparently that gets the value from the URL structure, not the form element. Or maybe it does both, not sure. But testing it, I seem to draw conclusion that it is getting it from URL, not form.

How can I make sure to access the form select value when making my comparisons in my PHP?

**Update**

The issue I'm having is with my canonical URL set in the header.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?occupation=administrator&position=network-administrator" />
```

that link is a indexed link on Google. I know I can just do an htaccess redirect to new link, but I'm just trying to figure out how to display the canonical url for this page.

it should be

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?occupation=administrator&position=network+administrator" />
```

the only difference is the `-` and the `+` in the query string.

Not all of my query strings have the +. Some have the -. But I display the content on both urls whether it has - or +. Either way, both urls get same page content.

But since the canonical is being created dynamically from the URI instead of what the value is from the form element, both content pages have 2 different canonicals.

Using _Get('value') is pulling the value from query string instead of form element. I know this because the form element value has a space between `network administrator` which gets urlencoded when form submits as `network+administrator`. So if I can compare to the form element value, I can set the proper canonical.

Comment: When you click the submit button, it reformats the url with all the `$_GET` variables so you are getting the variables from the form ultimately. Why not do `$_POST` instead?

Comment: $_post requires more things to implement and causes back button issues and other issues that _get fixes, plus it is only the URL, not important info being passed to server. I know it reformat with all the variables assigning to the query string. I still need to make comparison separately on the form element only, and in other places in my script, from the query string. It's needed.

Comment: Well, as is, you are accessing the `select` key/value pair properly from what I can see from your code.

Comment: As Rasclatt pointed out, its not like you're processing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for your various variables, you don't really have a more convenient way of accessing your GET parameters than $_GET[key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, you generate the HTML stuff upon invoking the required page, and then it's there. When interacting with a `form` element, you can put select values from the predefined (built with DOM) options, and you can pass that on to another file for processing. When you pass the values to that processor file, you can do so through various methodologies (for simplicity lets just take a look at the GET and the POST ones).

GET: will convert your form parameters to a url query which you have also posted in your question. **When your data arrives in the form of the GET array to your processor file, the file itself has no idea what kind of form it got it from, it only sees the query.**

POST: will encode your parameters into the transport layer, having it not apparently visible, however it is still there.

Using GET, you could manually form a query with intendedly invalid or malicious parameters and invoke your processor file with them. POST can also be programatically set to be malicious, but provides a convenient level of obscuration as such, and considering your question, might provide the effect you were looking for ("not directly taking it from the url").

**Edit**:

Code for simplifying form parameter handling according to visible pattern seen in OP question and comment:

```
$validKeys = array(
    'position',
    'occupation'
);

foreach ($validKeys AS $key){
    ${$key} = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : '';
}

/* other processing code */
```

With the above, if you had lets say 15 input parameters, you wouldn't have to go through all of them one-by-one, as `${$key}` allows you to create dynamically named variables, and you just update your `$validKeys` container (which could also be filled with values held in the database, and not manually controlled). From your updated comment I devised that you might be looking for something like this.

Comment: ok but _POST was causing other issues, like back button issues. I fixed back button issues with redirect and session but then the information being pulled from my array which is the title desc and post info for the content of the page was not lining up correctly to the comparison of the value in the query string because the previous session was still there when back button is clicked. So using _GET fixed a bunch of trouble. Is there no other way to test against the forms value? like using selectedindex?

Comment: Well, can't say much about the problems arising from using POST (would need to see more code to evaluate that issue), however, you could make an iteration for the key/values you are expecting. Example: specify white-listed `keys` in an array, iterate throuhg the array and check the existence of the $_GET[] parameter, if so, create $variable, otherwise do nothing. I'll update my answer in a minute with a specific code example.

Comment: saw your update edit. The issue I am faced with is my canonical url in the header of the page. It gets set based on what is in the query string. I need to set it based on what is in the form value. And according to my code it should, but it isn't. It is getting set by the query string. I'll post an update to my question to be more specific and give example. Hold on a bit.

Comment: btw, your edit is a nice piece of code for someone using lots of parameters, but I'm only using 2. But if I decide to use more, I'll def implement your code sample in your edit.

Comment: What about the possibility of using an underscore (`_`) instead of the hyphen (`-`) for the values, that might be handled correctly in your case.

Comment: not sure what you mean. `-` are common practice to use in a URL structure.

Comment: Re-read your updated description and am concluding that you'll want to have a look at the code part in your header generating your canonical tag. Right now it would be probably something that fetches the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and places it there - maybe you would want to look into that section and add a condition check along the lines of: `if GET is set with valid parameters THEN build the required URL format by iterating through the GET array processing as needed, ELSE just grab $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. if this still isn't what you're looking for, then I'm sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: that is exactly what I did. Got it straightened out. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Glad we figured it out in the end. :-)

Comment: Yep. Thank you for helping. I ended up using your snippet of code above just because I think it is cool and will come into use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are are you using GET which can be easily manipulated through URL.

I suggest changing the method to POST. It can be edited though using debuggers.